# routes with multiple files nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to route in multiple files

```
var routes=require('./routes');
```

in the routes/index.js

```
exports.inicio=require('./inicio')
exports.home=require('./home')
```

in the inicio.js

```
exports.index=function(req,res){res.render('index/index',{title: 'Bienvenido a Inmoweb'});}
```

in the home.js

```
exports.nosotros=function(req, res){res.render('index/nosotros',{title:'Nosotros'});}
```

when i console.log(routes)

```
{
inicio: {index:[function]}, 
home: {nosotros:[function]}
}
```

so i call in app

```
app.get('/',routes.inicio.index);
```

but i want to call like this

```
app.get('/',routes.index);
app.get('/nosotros',routes.nosotros);
```

and the console.log supose to be????

```
{
  index:[function], 
  nosotros:[function]
}
```

how to do that??? tnx all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `routes/index.js` can do the following:

```
exports.index = require('./inicio').index
exports.nosotros = require('./home').nosotros
```

---

You can make this even shorter by assigning directly to `module.exports` in `inico.js`:

```
module.exports = function(req,res){res.render('index/index',{title: 'Bienvenido a Inmoweb'});}
```

Now you can do this in `routes/index.js`:

```
exports.index = require('./inicio') //See the difference? 
// require('./inicio') now directly exports your route
exports.nosotros = require('./home').nosotros
```

Get the idea? :)

Comment: this is not the answer but i solve my problem with your help thank you

Comment: andre, what was your solution. It would help if you gave a bit more detail of how you solved the problem. I think that rdrey's solution and explanation are very good.